# how to fix double precision issue in java

Tags: java, android, double, double-precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java floats and doubles, how to avoid that 0.0 + 0.1 + … + 0.1 == 0.9000001?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257166/java-floats-and-doubles-how-to-avoid-that-0-0-0-1-0-1-0-9000001)

How can I overcome the precision issue with double multiplication in java android??Please note that I am converting a string value into double value.

eg: when I multiply two double value:

```
double d1 = Double.valueOf("0.3").doubleValue() * Double.valueOf("3").doubleValue();
System.out.println("Result of multiplication : "+d1);
```

I am getting the following result : 0.8999999999999999

Some of the results that i am getting are.

> 0.6*3=1.7999999999999998; 
>   0.2*0.2=0.04000000000000001; 
>   etc.

Instead of the above results I would like to get the following results.

> 0.3*3=0.9; 
>   0.6*3=1.8; 
>   0.2*0.2=0.04;

Please remember that I am not trying to round it to the nearest integer.

Comment: have you tried DecimalFormat? Example: (new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(doubleValue*1.00000));

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should really be using [java.math.BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to avoid any precision issues, and always use a BigDecimal(String) constructor.

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("0.3").multiply( new BigDecimal("3.0") );
```

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say using BigDecimal will avoid *any* precision issues. At the end of day we have to make some sacrifices to represent as large a possible range of numbers in a finite amount of memory.

Comment: @AdrianMouat, I am pretty sure if you use BigDecimal the way I specified (constructing it using `BigDecimal(String)` constructor), you will avoid any precision issues without sacrifices.

Comment: In the given examples, sure. There still have to be limits however.

Comment: @AdrianMouat the only limit is available memory. BigDecimal doesn't use floating point so it doesn't have this problem the way a double does.

Comment: @EJP, that doesn't contradict what I said. It seems BigDecimal throws exceptions when you're number can't be represented in decimal (e.g. 1/3). So you are sacrificing flexibility for precision here I suppose.

Comment: @AdrianMouat What does your last sentence mean?

Comment: @EJP That BigDecimal forces you to consider your inputs and possible exceptions. In return you get a greater level of precision.

Comment: you can use BigDecimal, but make sure that you use the construct of BigDecimal(String) rather than BigDecimal(double). see my post in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292783/5113415

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with multiplication. It starts with Double.valueOf("0.3"). That value can't be represented exactly in floating-point. You should use java.math.BigDecimal, and you should also Google for a page entitled "What every computer scientist should know about floating point".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a simple way of doing exactly what you ask for.

Like Strelok says, you should not be using a floating-point type if you need exact results.  However, for most purposes, it is enough to just specify a rounding precision for output.  The following code is close to, but not quite, what you want:

```
System.out.printf("Result of multiplication : %.1g\n", d1);
```

For more info on the syntax of printf, see [the java.util.Formatter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).