# Java - Double precision floating point

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to fix double precision issue in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103999/how-to-fix-double-precision-issue-in-java)

I have a small piece of code like this:

```
double number1 = 6;
double number2 = 5.99;
double result = number1 - number2;
```

However, the `result == 0.009999999999999787` instead of 0.01

I know it is the issue of IEEE 754 standard, but I don't understand why. Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: The closest `double` to 5.99 is 5.9900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375.

Comment: You got floating point problems, I feel bad for you, son. I've got .99 problems but infinite precision ain't .01.

Answer (score 4):

This is because float point numbers cannot be exactly represented with in binary system with limited bits (not without precision loss)

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: This is not loss of significance, it is inaccuracy of the actual representation.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no .01 in floating point numbers. The fractional bits are expressed as `1/root 2` so you can get something like .0125 or what you have there but there is not .01 in floating point numbers. If you need exact precision use integers instead.

Comment: If you need exact precision use BigDecimal http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: @KerrM Good call. I didn't know Java had a nice abstraction for you.